# How should I flag duplicated answers on different questions?

Tags: support, flags, late-answers

While reviewing the late answers queue, I tackled those 2 answers(I hope they are not deleted while asking the question):

- [Get Printer Status Code with win32print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303391/get-printer-status-code-with-win32print/65406346#65406346)
- [Python win32print printer status confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65406255/2359227)

Obviously, both answer are the same. I guess one of them should be deleted.

- Which one should I flag? Maybe both?
- Is there a flag for that? or should I just use the "in need of moderator intervention" and paste the link to the copy?

Comment: An automatic flag is raised for moderators when the same user posts *identical* answers to multiple questions. That's what happened in this case, and one of those answers was deleted as a result. In the general case, if you come across duplicate answers, you should: (1) check to see if they're from the same user, (2) check to see if they're plagiarized, and (3) if they're not tailored to the specific question that was asked, raise a moderator flag on one of the answers. You should *also* review the question(s) to see if they are eligible to be closed as duplicates.